# How to replace certain rows in numpy if they are better according to a self-specified function?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a matrix x, and a matrix p of the same structure and size.
One row represents the coordinates of an n-dimensional point.
I have a function f which takes a point (a row so to say) and computes a score for it.

Given x and p, I'd like to replace row i in p with row i in x if row i in x is smaller than row i in p according to my function f, formally:

for all row indices i do:
    p[i] = (x[i] if f(x[i]) < f(p[i]) else p[i])

Python's list comprehension is way to slow, so I need to do it in numpy, but I'm new to numpy and have tried and failed hard while trying to figure it out.
From other computations I already have, I've called them benchmarks for some reason, vectors for x and p where the value at index i is the score of row i.

Here's the relevant code:

```
benchmark_x = FUNCTION(x)
benchmark_p = FUNCTION(p)

# TODO Too slow, ask smart guys from StackOverflow
p = np.array([x[i] if benchmark_x[i] < benchmark_p[i] else p[i] for i in range(p.shape[0])])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this ?

```
pos = benchmark_x < benchmark_p
p[pos] = x[pos]
```